# Cannot build an Android app with Gradle, except with sudo

Tags: android, unix, ubuntu, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run a simple 'hello world' android app with gradle build. It builds fine if  I issue the command

> sudo ./gradlew build --> builds fine

But without sudo,

> ./gradlew build --> shows following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':MyStudioApplication'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':MyStudioApplication:_DebugCompile'.
      > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+.
        Required by:
            workspace:MyStudioApplication:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.621 secs
```

following is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

Please help

Comment: is the "build.gradle" you post the complete file? I don't see the dependency to the appcompat lib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a shot in the dark here, you may have run your initial gradle build with sudo which may have caused the artifacts to be downloaded and permisionned to root and are not accessible to your regular user. To test this assumption you may want to rename your local repository where gradle downloads the dependencies and rerun gradle as the standard user.

Comment: Also look at the permissions of everything in your SDK folder. If you installed the Google repository with root-only permissions, then it won't be able to read it when you build as non-root.

Answer (score 1):

This started happening to me after cleaning/building with sudo.

What worked for me was:

1. sudo ./gradlew clean
2. File -> Invalidate caches (check clear file system..., and restart)
3. delete manually one of the build folders, it was a multi-module project, and for some reason that module wasn't been deleted

Answer (score 0):

if you get the similar "cannot resolve symbol" appcompatactivity but running as sudo resolves things, try deleting the .AndroidStudio folder in your /home directory